# Can i run a magento2 store that sells goods to US and EU customers from a server that is in Germany(EU)?

Tags: magento2, pagespeed

I have a magento2 store that is running on a dedicated server that is located in Germany(EU). I started selling in EU so at that time it made sense to host it there.

Question is: if I want to start selling to US customers will it have a huge impact on performance? Should I expect a very slow loading time for US customers? Or should it be ok?

P.S I've done a few tests with two cloud servers with dedicated resources one from US/NY and one from EU/GE/Berlin, both of them running a basic apache installation. The loading time for the basic apache2 welcome page was US ~100ms and EU ~200ms (Both tests done on a pc in US/TX). Will this translate into a much longer loading time for my magento2 store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a single dedicated server in Germany, the store can still operate in other countries.

A [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) such as [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) or [Fastly](https://www.fastly.com/products/cdn) can reduce the loading time / latency of static resources and media. This is a fairly affordable way to achieve what you want, without too much extra effort. This makes a big difference in my experience. I personally use CloudFront, but the first time setup was somewhat complicated.

Magento Cloud uses Fastly as their default CDN. There is a free Magento 2 module that connects the CDN as well. I've never used Fastly, but I've heard good things about it.

Comment: can i use cloudflare for cdn? Would that be any good?

Comment: Yes! There's even an extension on the Magento Marketplace for Cloudflare. https://marketplace.magento.com/jetrails-magento2-cloudflare.html

Comment: I can't thank you enough (just please stop hunting, animals would like to live too...i guess?)! :D